# Database of arpabets sounds

Tags: data-request

I am currently working on speech synthesis with Labview as my platform.

I need a database of *mp3* files or *waveforms* corresponding to arpabets in English along with stress.

Where can I get and download such files?

I have seen many phoneme charts with their pronunciation and arpabet to phoneme chart; I can map arpabet to their pronunciation from this but it's quite a cumbersome task.

Any other alternative will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Would the CMU Pronouncing Dictionary match what you are looking for?
http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict